# pip install ecapture creates an error. How do I solve this?

Tags: python, installation, cmd, pip

I cannot install `ecapture 0.1.8`

Python version: `3.9.6`

pip: `21.2.2`

I am using Windows 10

I typed `pip install ecapture`
and got a whole bunch of collecting and installing messages, then this.:

```
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image
Failed to build scikit-image
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I also tried installing `scikit-image` and `wheel` individually but that didn't work. Does anyone know how to help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365790/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-scipy-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038673/could-not-build-wheels-for-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installed-directly have you tried either of these or other results for this error?

Comment: @Keon I tried the first one, same error, and the second one  loads for a super long time and outputs a huge error. I can copy it if you want

Comment: The [advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68068040/failed-to-build-scikit-image#comment120310343_68068040) may also be of assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365790/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-scipy-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  `pip3 install ecapture --no-binary :all:` and installed ecapture version 0.0.8 instead of 0.1.8

Answer (score 0):

1 upload from https://pypi.org/project/ecapture/#files
2 download ecapture-0.1.8-py3-none-any.whl

3 open cmd go to download directory `cd C:\Users\me\Downloads` (in my PC)

4 `pip install ecapture-0.1.8-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: upload from( go to