# Unable To Run AzureML Experiment with SDK - Failed to Build Wheel for pynacl / Exit status:1

Tags: python, azure, anaconda, azure-machine-learning-service, pynacl

I am trying to run a AzureML Experiment using sdk (following a Udemy course). When I try to use the Experiment.submit function the experiment prepares and then fails with the following error messages:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pynacl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pynacl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

The Azure env as created within my anaconda navigator for a short period of time and then gets removed.

Does anyone know how I can get around this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve `ERROR: Could not build wheels for pynacl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly` this error, try either of the following ways:

1. Install missing dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt install libpython3-dev build-essential
   ```
2. Upgrade pip:

   ```
   pip3 install --upgrade pip
   ```
3. Upgrade pip with setuptools wheel:

   ```
   pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
   ```
4. Reinstall PEP517:

   ```
   pip3 install p5py
   pip3 install PEP517
   ```

You can refer to  [ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365790/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-scipy-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installe), [Could not build wheels for _ which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly - Easy Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038673/could-not-build-wheels-for-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installed-directly) and [failed building wheel for pynacl](https://github.com/martomi/chiadog/issues/44)