# Error installing truefoundry experiment tracking library (pip install mlfoundry)

Tags: python, fastparquet, pep517

I tried to install mlfoundry on my Mac m1 laptop. It gives out the following error:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastparquet
Running setup.py clean for fastparquet
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [30 lines of output]
/Users/sohan04/work/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
```

Answer (score 3):

Execute the following command and try installing the truefoundry experimentation tracking library again.

```
SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1 pip install mlfoundry
```

You can also follow this link: [Could not build wheels for _ which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly - Easy Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038673/could-not-build-wheels-for-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installed-directly)