# Cartopy python Package (PEP 517) wheel building

Tags: python, python-3.x, cartopy, python-wheel, pep

I am trying to make a program with tropycal but it shows a wheel building error for a package dependency. Called Cartopy.

Pip3 Error:

`ERROR: Could not build wheels for cartopy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly.`

I tried a solution from another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038673/could-not-build-wheels-for-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installed-directly):

```
pip3 install cartopy --no-binary :all:
```

But it takes full CPU Power (100) and increases the CPU's temperature/thermal energy to 81 Celcius / 354.15 kelvin.

The Python version I am using is Python 3.8

I have Linux Mint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But it takes full CPU Power (100) and increases the CPU's
> temperature/thermal energy to 81 Celcius / 354.15 kelvin.

If the `no-binary` flag doesn't work *(as you described above)*, it can be due to cache issues.

Instead of `pip3 install cartopy --no-binary :all:` you may try `pip3 install cartopy --no-cache-dir`.

Another option would be to install the dependencies manually an then continue trying to install the package using pip. A list of the required dependencies can be found [here](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html#required-dependencies).

Another approach which I found on various forums (such as [this link](https://www.thiscodeworks.com/could-not-build-wheels-for-tokenizers-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installed-directly-python/6059a1d45570620014772be3#!)) is to upgrade `wheels` first before re-trying the `cartopy` installation. This can be done via `pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`!

As a last resort *(and this should only be used if no other options work)*, you may go ahead and disable the PEP 517 flag: `pip3 install cartopy --no-use-pep517`. This will most likely result in a lower quality build of the `cartopy` package and thus is not suggested.

Comment: Thanks, the installing the dependencies solution worked for me

Comment: No worries. Glad I was able to help @ScienceAJ

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the wheel from Christoph Gohlke ([link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)); search for `cartopy` and select the one for your version of Python (it looks like it is updated up to Python 3.10). Download the wheel and pip install, like:

```
pip install Cartopy‑0.20.2‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl
```

(for Python 3.8)

Whereby the file `Cartopy‑0.20.2‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` is in the folder where you start the `pip`.

Comment: Thanks, But Is it only for Windows?. I have Linux (Linux Mint to be specific)